# Navigation Controller image instead of text

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying to put a logo (png) file into my navigation controller. I found one solution that "worked" but it didn't scale down the image to fit, thus is was massive

This is the code im using thus far, but it makes the image huge

```
let logoImage:UIImage = UIImage(named: "logo.png")!
    self.navigationItem.titleView = UIImageView(image: logoImage)
```

Comment: @DharmeshKheni do you want ALL my code or just the code that i tried before that made it huge?

Comment: Code related with your nav controller image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
let logo = UIImage(named: "logo.png")
let imageView = UIImageView(image:logo)
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit  //you need to set this.

self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView
```

And if you want to give height and width then add this:

```
imageView.frame.size.width = 200
imageView.frame.size.height = 45
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in 2 ways: programmatically or via XCode:

An easy way is via XCode. For it, drag `view` from the object library and drag it to your navigation bar. Later drag into your `view` in navigation bar `UIImageView` from object library. That's all.

Or you can do all of this programmatically.

```
    var myView = UIView()
    var imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "your_image_here")

    myView.addSubview(imageView)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(myView)
```